# How query can i use to get a best seller?

Tags: sql

This is my database sample

```
id/cart_id/title/quantity
1    1    bbok1    2
2    2    book2    3
3    3    book1    2
```

So in this case I have book1 with a total of 4 sales and book2 with 3 sales.
However if I use order by quantity it would show book2 then book1.

How do I use the query or php code to get the same item and make it book1 4 sales, book2 3 sales?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT
  title,
  SUM(quantity) AS total_sales
FROM
  books
GROUP BY
  title
ORDER BY
  total_sales DESC
```